# JS mousedown won't work on appended text tags

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, mousedown

With two texts in p tags, the thing I want to do is when one is clicked it moves a bit and then other text is deleted, but re added after first one is clicked again. The problem is that when tag is deleted and when it gets added back the mousedown function is not working at all. I have to mention that mousedown works normal on the text/tag that is first clicked when page loads and only that tag stays clicktable.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    var upPoBool = false;
    
    //first part
    $('#firstPart').mousedown(function() {
        if(upPoBool == false){
            var firstPart = document.getElementById("firstPart");
            firstPart.classList.toggle("firstPartToggle");
            
            //delete second part
            $("#secondPart").remove();
            
            upPoBool = true;
            
        } else if(upPoBool == true){
            var firstPart = document.getElementById("firstPart");
            firstPart.classList.toggle("firstPartToggle");
            
            $('#firstPart:last').after('<p id="secondPart">Second part move NEW</p>');

            upPoBool = false;
        }

    });
    
    var upBaBool = false;
    
    //second part
    $('#secondPart').mousedown(function() {
        if(upBaBool == false){
            var secondPart = document.getElementById("secondPart");
            secondPart.classList.toggle("secondPartToggle");
            
            //delete first part
            $("#firstPart").remove();
            
            upBaBool = true;
            
        } else if(upBaBool == true){
            var secondPart = document.getElementById("secondPart");
            secondPart.classList.toggle("secondPartToggle");

            $('#secondPart:last').before('<p id="firstPart">First part move NEW</p>');
            
            upBaBool = false;
        }

    });
    
});
```

```css
.firstPartToggle{
    margin-left: 5rem;
}

.secondPartToggle{
    margin-left: 5rem;
}


#firstPart{
    position: absolute;
    top: 2rem;
    
    z-index: 101;
}

#secondPart{
    position: absolute;
    top: 4rem;
    
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>ClickTestFAQ</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Something test:</p>
    <div id="testingDiv">
        <p id="firstPart">First part move</p>
        <p id="secondPart">Second part move</p>
    </div>
    
    <!--Scripts-->
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    
</body>
    
</html>
```

Tags are not cutting into one another, so z-index is not doing anything, I also tried to put them in separate div but the result was same.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/remove/: _"In addition to the elements themselves, **all bound events** and jQuery data **associated with the elements are removed**. To remove the elements without removing data and events, use .detach() instead."_

Comment: @CBroe may I ask if event delegation is useful in this scenario? `$(document).on('mousedown', '#firstPart', ...`

Comment: @GrafiCode which approach would you use instead of used one?

Comment: I would use event delegation, as stated in my comment above. Instead of binding an event listener directly to your elements `$('#firstPart').mousedown(...)`, you can delegate the event on a parent element. `$(document).on('mousedown', '#firstPart', ...`. I think ithis should work even if you remove and then re-add the target element. https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/  `Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future`

Comment: even better: `$('#testingDiv').on('mousedown', '#firstPart', ...`

Comment: @GrafiCode oh ok I get it, yea that would be much easier, thanks for the tip I will definitely try that approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove an element from DOM, youre also remove the bound events (also your mousedown event). That means that you need to add this mousedown event again after you recreate your element.

Here is an solution for your exact problem:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    let upPoBool = false;
    let upBaBool = false;

        const firstPartHandler = () => {
        if(upPoBool == false){
            var firstPart = document.getElementById("firstPart");
            firstPart.classList.toggle("firstPartToggle");
            
            //delete second part
            $("#secondPart").remove();
            
            upPoBool = true;
        } else if(upPoBool == true){
            var firstPart = document.getElementById("firstPart");
            firstPart.classList.toggle("firstPartToggle");
            
            $('#firstPart:last').after('<p id="secondPart">Second part move NEW</p>');
                    $('#secondPart').mousedown(secondPartHandler);

            upPoBool = false;
        }
    }

        const secondPartHandler = () => {
        if(upBaBool == false){
            var secondPart = document.getElementById("secondPart");
            secondPart.classList.toggle("secondPartToggle");
            
            //delete first part
            $("#firstPart").remove();
            
            upBaBool = true;
        } else if(upBaBool == true){
            var secondPart = document.getElementById("secondPart");
            secondPart.classList.toggle("secondPartToggle");

            $('#secondPart:last').before('<p id="firstPart">First part move NEW</p>');
                    $('#firstPart').mousedown(firstPartHandler);
            
            upBaBool = false;
        }
    }
    
    //first part
    $('#firstPart').mousedown(firstPartHandler);
    
    //second part
    $('#secondPart').mousedown(secondPartHandler);
});
```

```css
.firstPartToggle{
    margin-left: 5rem;
}

.secondPartToggle{
    margin-left: 5rem;
}


#firstPart{
    position: absolute;
    top: 2rem;
    
    z-index: 101;
}

#secondPart{
    position: absolute;
    top: 4rem;
    
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>ClickTestFAQ</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Something test:</p>
    <div id="testingDiv">
        <p id="firstPart">First part move</p>
        <p id="secondPart">Second part move</p>
    </div>
    
    <!--Scripts-->
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    
</body>
    
</html>
```

Another solution could be to hide the elements instead of removing them. Here is an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    let activeItem = null
    
    $('#testingDiv p').mousedown(function() {
        if (!activeItem) {
            $('#testingDiv p').not(this).hide()
            $(this).addClass('active')
            activeItem = $(this)
        } else {
            $('#testingDiv p').show()
            $(this).removeClass('active')
            activeItem = null
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.active {
    margin-left: 5rem;
}


#firstPart {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2rem;
    z-index: 101;
}

#secondPart {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4rem;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ClickTestFAQ</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
      <p>Something test:</p>
      <div id="testingDiv">
          <p id="firstPart">First part move</p>
          <p id="secondPart">Second part move</p>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You said: _That means that you need to add this mousedown event again after you recreate your element._ -  and then, instead of providing code for that solution, you offered some other alternative. Why not adding code for what OP asked?

Comment: _The OP don't asked for code examples_ - That's implicit here.

Comment: Thanks so much, thats just what I needed to do, did not know that you need to re-add handlers also.